# Relations between the knapsack problem, the bin packing problem, and the set packing problem?

Tags: knapsack-problems, packing

I wonder what relations are between [the knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), [the bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) and [the set packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing)?

From their mathematical formulations, I don't see the first two belong to the third one i.e. the set packing problem, although I feel the third one sounds more general than the other two.

Or under what conditions there are some conversions between each other?

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't these all NP-complete? All NP-complete problems can be converted to eachother in polynomial time. See [wp:Karp's_21_NP-complete_problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems).

Comment: @Realz_Slaw: Thanks! Your point from polynomial reduction is correct. I was asking about relations and conversions at the level of problem formulations. Or are these two points of view the same?

Comment: Well you could be asking for a more direct conversion, and/or a human explanation about their relationship, as the reductions given for one NP-complete problem to another can be multi-step (conversion to multiple intermediate problems) and lose a lot of easily "explainable" information. Or you could be asking something I simply don't understand.

Comment: Are you asking about "one-one reduction"?

Comment: @Reza: it can be that or any others.